# What type of Google App is it?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I would like to write a Google App for GMail that will look like the Trello app:

[image]

I don't know what type of Google App to choose for it.
As far as I know the GMailApp cannot use UI class. They cannot also be bound to GMail container like to Sheets or Documents. The Sidebar gadget has been deprecated. It is not the Chrome extension because it works also in Firefox.
Is it Web App?
Can I see this app's manifest or source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a gmail add-on:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/

Comment: So, there are numerous Google extensions: Google Apps, Google Gadgets, Chrome Extensions and GMail Add-ons.

Comment: Yes, and gmail add-ons are the latest addition, they open up lots of new possibilities!

Comment: Who added minus to answer? Please elaborate.